# Display 4 chronological posts starting with a random post

Tags: php, functions, get-posts

I know that I can display 4 random posts by doing something like:

```
get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=4');
```

What I'm trying to achieve is starting with a random item, but then showing the next 3 posts that are in chronological order.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

```
$posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=1'); 

foreach($posts as $post) { 
    the_title();

    //get next 3 chronological posts and loop
}
```

I guess I need to use something like the 'offset' parameter, but with a post id instead of a position?

Comment: So you need a random post, and then three posts that are published before or after this specific random post

Comment: @PieterGoosen Three posts after the randomly chosen one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random offset we might try:

```
$ppp    = 4;  
$total  = wp_count_posts()->publish;    

$offset = $total < $ppp ? 0 : rand( 0, $total - $ppp );

$posts = get_posts( [
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'offset'         => $offset
] );
```

### Example:

Let's take `$ppp` as 4 and assume `$total` is 6.

Then are three possibilities for the `$offset`, namely 0, 1 and 2:

```
Nr  Offset Selections
1   0      x
2   1      x x
3   2      x x x
4   3      x x x
5   4        x x
6   5          x
```

so

```
$offset = $total < $ppp ? 0 : rand( 0, $total - $ppp );
```

would give:

```
$offset = rand( 0, 6 - 4 );
```

or just

```
$offset = rand( 0, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One question though - Would this not just get a random post followed by the first 3 posts, rather than three following on from the random one?

Comment: oh, guess I misunderstood your question, you want to display 4 posts, with a random offset? Currently I just fetch a random one, and then just the 3 newest, excluding the random one.

Comment: Basically, yes. So essentially, on one page load, you might see posts 5,6,7,8 - Then another you might see 14,15,16,17 - or 9,10,11,12 etc.

Comment: ok, but then we would need an extra condition for the random offset, so it will always be <= total_posts - 4 and total_posts >= 4. something like $offset = rand( 0, total_posts - 4 )  @LoboDemon

Comment: If it makes it easier, it's probably not the end of the world if there aren't always 4 shown - Like posts_per_page works as a maximum items to show, if there aren't 3 more posts after the random item, it just shows however many there are?

Comment: Using your update seems to have done the trick! Thanks very much :)

Comment: Nice approach with the offset. You can also use a `date_query` ;-)

Comment: yes that's an interesting approach using the date_query  @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using a `date_query`.

- We will get the one random post
- We will then use a `date_query` to get the other 3 posts adjacent to that one random post

Here is the function we will use: (***NOTE:*** I have commented the code to make it easy to follow, and the code requires PHP 5.4+)

```
function get_random_posts( $args = [], $direction = 'after' )
{
    /**
     * Lets first get our random post, then work from there. We will be using the same 
     * exact arguments for all our queries we need to run. We do however need to modify
     * some a bit. We will save the default args to a another variable and then modify
     * the args to pass to the first query.
     *
     * We will let WP_Query handle the sanitation and validation from the
     * array of arguments.  
     */
    $random_args                   = $args;
    $random_args['orderby']        = 'rand';
    $random_args['posts_per_page'] = 1;

    $random_post = get_posts( $random_args );

    /**
     * We will o get the adjacent posts from the random one. We will be 
     * using the default $args again
     *
     * We will need to sort out the amount of posts to get from the adjacent
     * post query first before  we go along. We need to deduct one from the amount
     * of posts to adjust for the random post
     */
    if ( isset( $args['posts_per_page'] ) ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = ( $args['posts_per_page'] - 1 );
    } else {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = ( get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) - 1 );
    }

    // Create our date query to get the adjacent posts  
    $date_query = [
        [
            $direction  => $random_post[0]->post_date,
            'inclusive' => false
        ]
    ];
    $args['date_query'] = $date_query;

    // Set the order parameter according to direction
    if ( $direction === 'after' ) {
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    } else {
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    }

    $adjacent_query = get_posts( $args );   

    // Merge and return the posts
    return array_merge( $random_post, $adjacent_query );
}
```

As you can see, the first parameter in the function is `$args`. This wil be an array of arguments that you would normally pass to `WP_Query`. The second parameter, `$direction` will be the direction of the adjacent posts, either `before` or `after` according to needs.

You would use the function as follow:

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 4 // The amount of posts to get
    // Any other arguments you might need
];
$q = get_random_posts( $args );

foreach ( $q as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title();

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This looks good! Will have a go at implementing tomorrow. This solution may be better suited as I may need to include some metakeys into my query. Thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure. As always, if you have any issue, feel free to leave me a comment ;-). Enjoy

Comment: Glad you implemented the idea, nice to see different approaches ;-)

Comment: @birgire thanks. I was actually busy with this from the word go ;-). But it is as you always say, very nice to see different approches. I really never ever though of your approach. This way we all learn in some way or the other and the community really benefit from answeres like these